# How do I use v$session, v$sqlarea and v$process in Oracle to troubleshoot blocked sessions?

Tags: oracle

v$session, v$sqlarea and v$process provide lot of information.  What information from these views can I use for troubleshooting blocked sqlplus sessions?

Comment: You use those views when you need the information they provide. Your question isn't focused enough at all - there are literally thousands of scripts that use these views floating about on the internet. If you're trying to fix/track down a specific problem, please explain that. Otherwise, a "list of scripts" question isn't a good fit for this site.

Comment: @Mat I have made this question more focussed.  Please let me know if this question is now okay.

Comment: You can potentially use many of the columns in those views.  Check our the manual for more information on [v$session](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3016.htm#i1414383), [v$sqlarea](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3064.htm#i1419171), and [v$process](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_2101.htm#i1411655).  The most important column will probably be v$session.final_blocking_session.

Comment: @jonearles I went through the manual but it is not developer friendly.  For example, I don't understand the meaning of "No holder", "GLOBAL" and "Unknown" (values of blocking_session_status).  Should I kill all the sessions having these values or should I kill only those having "No holder" etc

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan I've never used that column before.  I don't have a specific script for this.  My general strategy for locks is to find out what session is blocking (from v$session.final_blocking_session), who owns that session (v$session.schemaname/osuser/machine, etc), and what SQL they are running (v$sql.sqltext).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using v$session you can

- list all sessions
- identify active sessions with STATUS='ACTIVE' and how long it was running LAST_CALL_ET

  see running sql with SQL_ID or SQL_ADDR

  If session is waiting check *WAIT* columns for current wait details.

V$PROCCES is mostly with SESS_ADDR to find process ID of Oracle background process and application process ID.
V$SQLAREA and V$SQL provide text of SQL and more details for each SQL still in cache.

Start with this and explore more details from official Oracle documentation...